# Not sure the loop I need to use every two variables

Tags: php

I have a problem where I have an array $user.

I have `$_SESSION['players']` which has the total amount of `$user`.

I need a function where I can take the user1 and 2 and use them. Then move on to user3 and 4 and use them, and so on.. until I have used all the players. Obviously the total `$user[$i]` would be `players-1`.

Anyone have a solution for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Would this suit your needs? This requires that there be an even number of players to work properly though, unless you stick in a check for odd numbers:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $_SESSION['players']; $i += 2) {
    $userA = $user[$i];
    $userB = $user[$i + 1];

    // Do things with $userA and $userB variables...
}
```

Comment: Once you've got the FOR loop incrementing by 2, adding an extra conditional to handle the case of an odd number of users is fairly easy.

Comment: This is perfect. I will always have an even amount of players. I really need to get more creative with my for loops. I only think of them in the convential $i++ way!

Comment: @user511886: What you can do with FOR goes way beyond i++.  To get your creativity flowing, what about a loop that uses i = length; i>= 0; i--;?  Or a loop that uses i = i * 2?

Comment: Off-topic, @user511886 in PHP land it's better to pre-increment $i (`++$i`) for performance purposes (it's marginally faster).

Comment: @DGH - very crazy loops. When have you used those before?

Comment: @zzzzBov - I will bear this in mind, knew you can use either but wasn't aware pre-increment was quicker.

Comment: @user511886: The one with i-- is great for when you need to start at the end of a list and work backwards toward the beginning.  The second is just a crazy example to show that you can work outside the box, but I could imagine it being used for something where powers of 2 are involved (e.g. you want to check the 1st, 2nd, 4th, 8th, 16th, etc. elements of a list or bits of a number)

Comment: Very very interesting. I will keep a more open mind from now on with regards to my for loops. Without doubt, the most used loop from personal experience.

Answer (score 2):

just because you're taught how to use `for` loops in one way does not mean that you're stuck continuing to use them the way you were taught:

<del>$length = count($users);</del>

```
$length = $_SESSION['players'];
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i += 2)
{
  if (!isset($user[$i], $user[$i + 1])) break;
  $userOne = $user[$i];
  $userTwo = $user[$i+1];
  //do stuff
}
```

---

I realized that isset wasn't necessary, the for call could be modified more:

```
$length = $_SESSION['players'];
for ($i = 0; ($i + 1) < $length; $i += 2)
{
  $userOne = $user[$i];
  $userTwo = $user[$i+1];
  //do stuff
}
```

EDIT to change how the length was calculated:
EDIT to validate that user exists
EDIT to add consolidated version

Comment: Thanks for this. I really need to think about using for loops in a better way!